# Access control rule doesn't appear in ACL

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a module defined this way:

```
class ProjectVersion(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.version' ...
```

and a menu item:

```
  <act_window id="action_project_versions"
    name="Project versions"
    res_model="project.version"
    view_mode="tree,form" />
  <menuitem id="menu_project_version"
    parent="project.menu_project_config"
    name="Versions"
    action="action_project_versions"
    sequence="4" />
```

I have a file ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_project_version_user,project.version user,model_project_version,project.group_project_user,1,0,0,0
access_project_version_manager,project.version manager,model_project_version,project.group_project_manager,1,1,1,1
```

Users with uid > 1 didn't see new menu item and can't edit version field in form view (

> access error appears "You can't access requested document ... model:
>   project.version"

), also new rule didn't uppear in settings>technical>security>access control list

What is wnong with my file ir.model.access.csv ?

Comment: Did you add the users uid>1 into group ptoject_user/project_manager?

Comment: I have severel users in gruou project_manager and no one in project_user. Should I try to create a project_user? I suppose something wrong with keyword in ir.model.access.csv . Does odoo say if identifiers in ir.model.access.csv are unknown ?

Comment: Just open your group settings->groups->project_user. and add a new user under users tab. also check access right tab to see the access rights you given to this group. and try to login to the user account you have added to project_user group.

Comment: It's clear, I thought Admin belongs only to project_managers group, now I see he also belongs to project_users. So the deal is somethere else, but not in users settings. I'll try to create access rule manually, export it and compare to one presented in initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it works only if I make manually in settings Acess control Lists, export them. Then I delete manually created Access control lists.
Export file contents:

```
"id","name","model_id/id","group_id/id","perm_write","perm_create","perm_unlink","perm_read"
"__export__.ir_model_access_484","access_project_version manager","project_version.model_project_version","project.group_project_manager","True","True","True","True"
"__export__.ir_model_access_485","access_project_version user","project_version.model_project_version","project.group_project_user","False","False","False","True"
```

I replaced first colunm with

```
"access_project_version_manager"
"access_project_version_user"
```

I have placed new ir.model.access.csv in security folder of my module, updated module and now it works!